How can I show fullcalendar in a modal dialog
I am trying to show FullCalendar inside a modal dialog. The full calendar can be viewed inside a div element. But I want to show it inside a modal dialog.
Here is the code:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="getCalendarEvents()">Depot Calendar</button>
<div class="row">
    <div class="att-area" id="empcalendar">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
   var empevents = [];
   function getCalendarEvents(empevents) {   
      
        $('#empcalendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#empcalendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'month',  
            handleWindowResize: true, 
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
            },
            eventLimit: true,
            events: empevents          
            
        });
    }
</script>

empevents array shows the data is as given below
{empid: 159, title: 'XXXXX - UnPaid', start: Tue Jan 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), end: Tue Jan 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), allDay: true}
{empid: 9, title: 'YYY - UnPaid', start: Tue Jan 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), end: Tue Jan 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), allDay: true}


I don't think anybody would be happy to give you assistance in future if you keep giving no response to their solution/workaround and not sharing complete code for troubleshooting. If the post is helpful to solve your issue, pls vote up or mark, if they are not helpful, please give your feedback, share more defails about your concerns, or share more codes.

"I want" isn't a question. Any reason you couldn't try this yourself? Did you attempt anything, or research how it could be done? Where did you get stuck? What's your question? Reminder: [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue

For how to show fullcalendar in a modal dialog, a working demo you could follow:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showCalendarModal()">Depot Calendar</button>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div class="modal fade" id="calendarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="calendarModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="calendarModalLabel">Depot Calendar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="empcalendar"></div> <!-- Calendar container -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Array of events to be displayed in the calendar
    var empevents = [
        { empid: 159, title: 'XXXXX - UnPaid', start: '2024-01-02', end: '2024-01-02', allDay: true },
        { empid: 9, title: 'YYY - UnPaid', start: '2024-01-02', end: '2024-01-02', allDay: true }
    ];

    // Function to show the modal and initialize FullCalendar
    function showCalendarModal() {
        $('#calendarModal').modal('show'); // Show the modal
    }

    // When the modal is shown, initialize or refresh the FullCalendar
    $('#calendarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        initializeCalendar(empevents);
    });

    // Function to initialize or refresh FullCalendar
    function initializeCalendar(events) {
        $('#empcalendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); // Destroy any existing calendar instance
        $('#empcalendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'month',
            handleWindowResize: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            eventLimit: true,
            events: events // Pass the events data to the calendar
        });
    }

    // Function to dynamically update the calendar events if you need
    function getCalendarEvents(newEvents) {
        empevents = newEvents; 
        initializeCalendar(empevents); 
    }


</script>


Hi Rena
I applied your code but it does not work since there is no calling full calendar in you javascript. I cannot see the calling  of getCalendarEvents().

Hi @Alevel, getCalendarEvents is just for the further coding if you need dynamically update the fullcalendar. So you do not see I call it, in your current scenario, is it no need call it, the full calendar display is only work by initializeCalendar. Pls share the error message for not working.

Hi @Alevel, and did you copy all my code? Still not working? If so, pls F12 in the browser and check the Console tab if any error message.
